# How to get rid of a white space that develops when the browser size is reduced?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://stackoverflowproblems.site88.net/index.html

Above is the current site. In terms of layout, there are no problems. But, when you minimize it to phone screen size (in your browser), a white space develops in between the two white spaces. What could be the problem? This white space is still part of that Div as I saw when I inspected it, but the content is not filling into that white part. See for yourself in the website above. ^ Also, on other resolutions the layout may look weird. If so, I would appreciate a solution for that too. Thanks!

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin-top: 20px` of the first `h1` created the space between the "2 black divs", which is what I think you meant by the "two white spaces" in your question. Setting it to `margin-top: 0", or

```
h1.first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

will solve your problem

Comment: That worked perfectly! Should've inspected more, can't believe I missed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.h1, .h2, .h3, h1, h2, h3{
margin-top:0 !important
;}
```

please add the above code in your css